# ko cant get update function triggered

Tags: jquery, knockout-2.0

I am writing my first bindinghandler and having some issues. When entering 'up' or 'down' the number property should increase / decrease with 1. However the update is not triggered when I tab out of the textbox:

html:

```
<input data-bind="whichdirection: direction" /><button>test</button>
nr value:<span data-bind="text:number"></span>
```

script:

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.whichdirection = {
       update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
           var value = valueAccessor();
           if (value == 'up') {
               ko.observable(ko.observable() + 1);
           }
           if (value == 'down') {
               ko.observable(ko.observable() - 1);
           }
       }
   }

   vm = function () {
       this.number = ko.observable(1);
   }
```

ko.applyBindings(new vm());

Also this is the jsfiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/Sb67M/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to catch keydown event by KO binding or by jQuery inside custom bindings. Then you can get access number variable which can be updated (decrease/increase).

update HTML structure

```
<input data-bind="whichdirection: number, value: number" />
<button>test</button>nr value:<span data-bind="text:number"></span>
```

update JS code

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.whichdirection = {
       init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
           var value = valueAccessor();
           $(element).keydown(function(event) {
               if (event.keyCode === 38) {
                   value(value() + 1);
               } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
                   value(value() - 1);
               }
           });
       }
   }
```

jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/BWn75/